# aiogram webhook, нужно получить текст отправленного на хук post запроса

Tags: python, telegram-bot, nginx, aiogram, webhook

Есть VPSка, в качестве веб-сервера nginx, тг бот на вебхуках. Сам по себе бот работает без проблем, получает пост-запросы от телеграмма на https://domain.zone/webhook, но мне бы хотелось, чтобы на тот же самый вебхук могли отправлять запросы другие сервисы. Если максимально обобщить вопрос, то вот что я хочу знать: Как для вот этого кода из примера сделать обработку получаемых post-запросов, чтобы, например, запрос от телеграма обрабатывался как запрос от телеграма, а post-запрос из того же postman (либо реального сервиса, без разницы), например, просто выводился в консоль:

```
NGINX_HOST = os.environ.get('NGINX_HOST') 
WEBHOOK_HOST = f'https://{NGINX_HOST}'
WEBHOOK_PATH = '/webhook'
WEBHOOK_URL = f'{WEBHOOK_HOST}{WEBHOOK_PATH}'
WEBAPP_HOST = '0.0.0.0' 
WEBAPP_PORT = 3001



async def on_startup(dp):
    await bot.set_webhook(WEBHOOK_URL)

async def on_shutdown(dp):
    await bot.delete_webhook()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if IS_WEBHOOK == 1:
        start_webhook(
            dispatcher=dp,
            webhook_path=WEBHOOK_PATH,
            on_startup=on_startup,
            on_shutdown=on_shutdown,
            skip_updates=True,
            host=WEBAPP_HOST,
            port=WEBAPP_PORT,)
    else:
        executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Если для этого варианта кода это сделать невозможно, то какие технологии лучше применить, хотелось бы понять сам принцип. Возможно, следует сделать отдельный вебхук, условно https://domain.zone/anotherwebhook, но тогда как и на чем его запускать, если веб-сервер самого aiogram для этого не подходит, а получаемая на этот хук информация при этом должна попадать в бота.